# download link with accent

Tags: php, file-upload, internationalization

Yes i am french, and have to deal with people that upload files with accent... in html and php i have done a little file lister and a link to all those files when click on the name... really simple...

the problem is, all the normal file download perfect when click on... except for the one with accent in the name... it return a error 404

how to encode the href string to get the proper donwload link to get the file

example : http://nivelaxe.com/FTP/yvonne/14-04-19_P%C3%A2ques.zip shold be fine, but NO...
the file on server is : [http://nivelaxe.com/FTP/yvonne/14-04-19_Pâques.zip](http://nivelaxe.com/FTP/yvonne/14-04-19_P%C3%A2ques.zip)

i am lost, and google dont help !

--

new test link :

- test-file 1 (no accent) http://nivelaxe.com/FTP/yvonne/test_file.txt
- test_file 2 (with accent) [http://nivelaxe.com/FTP/yvonne/test_accent_èàç.txt](http://nivelaxe.com/FTP/yvonne/test_accent_%C3%A8%C3%A0%C3%A7.txt)

the content of the file with accent is : èàç

Comment: Are you sure that your file is on the server with the name : "14-04-19_Pâques.zip", because your link doesn't work.

Comment: i upload test file and add link to the question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to url urlencode last part of url and the result is this:
http://nivelaxe.com/FTP/yvonne/test_accent_%E8%E0%E7.txt

Is this your uploaded file?

Also works for zip file which you mentioned in question:
http://nivelaxe.com/FTP/yvonne/14-04-19_P%E2ques.zip

Comment: the content of the file is : èàç

Comment: following up ... why the content is NOT AS SUPPOSED TO BE... encoding problem ?

Comment: on sub problem if when i try to SAVE the file on my desktop... the name is : test_accent_%E8%E0%E7.txt (NOT NICE)

Comment: when I download the txt file, it was OK, but in browser is some encoding problem, maybe you have to send some headers

Comment: Yes you're right, name of file is not nice. You can do two things: save file with nice name after user uploads it. Or prepare some service for downloading files where you can send headers with nice name.